# Can I use passive voice with to instead of by?

Tags: passive-voice

Can I use to instead of by in this passive sentence?

It has been known to him.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, 'known' often uses 'to', although it may also use 'by':

> These facts are already known to the investigators.
>   
>  These facts are already known by the investigators.

This is a peculiarity of 'know'. I haven't found any other verb that allows a similar passive construction with 'to'.

Comment: The one with *to* isn't a passive construction, as far as I can see - in that version, *known* is an adjective. There are lots of other adjectives that work the same way, e.g. *the story was familiar to him*.

Comment: I would argue that _known to_ is using _known_ as an adjective, not a passive verb.

Comment: The answer to the question is yes. known + to the investigators. And yes, an adjective, not a passive verb.